# Removing array item on button click

Tags: javascript, html

How do I remove an item on click? This is what I currently have:

```js
function deleteUser(name) {
   var person = name;

   const array = ['John','Mark','Andy'];
   const index = array.indexOf(person);
   if (index > -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
   }
   console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteUser('John')"> Delete User </button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Mark')"> Delete User </button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Andy')"> Delete User </button>
```

I can already remove value on array but I am getting different result.
Ex. When I delete on a value `John`. I am getting `['Mark','Andy']` but when I delete `Mark` I am getting `['John','Andy']`.

I want to remove the item on array when it is click

Comment: So you want to make an array with deletedUsers ? And whenever you delete someone you push that user into the deletedUsers array

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can define the `array` outside of the function and using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove items. Important thing is `.filter()` creates a new array so you need to reassign in your function the result. See from the documentation:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Try as the following:

```js
let array = ['John','Mark','Andy'];

const deleteUser = name => {
   array = array.filter(e => e !== name);
   console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteUser('John')"> Delete User </button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Mark')"> Delete User </button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Andy')"> Delete User </button>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the array outside the function otherwise it get reinitialized every time.

Also the filter method is a great function to do this, however if you want you can still do it with splice too as long you keep the array outside of your function.

```js
var array = ['John','Mark','Andy'];

function deleteUser(name) {
   array = array.filter(n => n !== name);
   console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteUser('John')"> Delete User John</button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Mark')"> Delete User Mark </button>
<button onclick="deleteUser('Andy')"> Delete User Andy</button>
```

Comment: Note that the `indexOf` plus `splice` is more efficient. It doesn't create a new array and stops iterating after a single match is found. The `filter` solution is more readable imo. In the end it comes down to preference.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Good note, didn't know about the performance. Thanks.